# GuestAdditions seems to be installed (6.0.2) correctly, but not running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

after upgrading VirtualBox to V.6.0.2, Vagrant V2.2.3 and homestead to release 8.0.0 each time I run `vagrant up` I get:

> GuestAdditions seems to be installed (6.0.2) correctly, but not running

I tried to install `GuestAdditions` manually as below:

- Download the latest `GuestAdditions` iso from https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.0.2
- Run VirtualBox and on VM settings I clicked `Devices` -> `Insert Guest Additions CD Image`
- Log in to the guest server/VM
- Mount the CDROM `sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom`
- Change into the mounted directory with the command `cd /media/cdrom`
- Install the necessary dependencies with the command `sudo apt-get install -y dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
- Change to the root user with the command `sudo su`
- Install the Guest Additions package with the command `./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`
- Reboot the VM

But I still get that warning:

> GuestAdditions seems to be installed (6.0.2) correctly, but not running

Please advise

Comment: First uninstall the old one and then install the new one.

Comment: do you think I didn't do that!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After struggling for a longtime with `GuestAdditions` I decided to uninstall `vagrant-vbguest` plugin, and voilà! It solved the issue.

`vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vbguest`

Comment: This does'nt solves the problem. This more like running awas from problems because you don't want to care about it!

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the readme file for [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest)
the plugin looks at the modules `vboxguest` and `vboxsf` in `/proc/modules` to decide whether the `GuestAdditions` are running:

> #### Linux
>
> This option is available on all Linux type installers.
>
> - `:running_kernel_modules` (default: `["vboxguest", "vboxsf"]`) The list used to check for the "running" state.
>   Each of these modules need to appear at the beginning of a line in `/proc/modules`.

In case you don't use the vboxsf filesystem (for instance you use nfs) then you get this message
and the guest additions are reinstalled on every vagrant up.

The solution is to add the following line to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vbguest.installer_options = { running_kernel_modules: ["vboxguest"] }
```

So now vboxsf is not used for checking the "running" state.

I use it as follows in my Vagrantfile:

```
if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-vbguest")
    config.vbguest.installer_options = { running_kernel_modules: ["vboxguest"] }
    config.vbguest.auto_update = true
end
```